# spryker extend DummyPaymentHandlerPlugin class

Tags: spryker

I am new to spryker and I want to extend this class DummyPaymentHandlerPlugin. I tried by adding the class to the factory but is not working. Can anyone help me to do this

Comment: Can you provide more details? Maybe showing some code?

Answer (score 0):

Extending plugins in Spryker is possible. But instead of changing the factory method, you just have to change the use statement in the appropriate dependency provider.

In your case, it's `\Pyz\Yves\CheckoutPage\CheckoutPageDependencyProvider::extendPaymentMethodHandler`:

```
    protected function extendPaymentMethodHandler(Container $container): Container
    {
        $container->extend(static::PAYMENT_METHOD_HANDLER, function (StepHandlerPluginCollection $paymentMethodHandler) {
            $paymentMethodHandler->add(new DummyPaymentHandlerPlugin(), DummyPagmentConfig::PAYMENT_PROVIDER_NAME);

            return $paymentMethodHandler;
        });

        return $container;
    }
```